# Cannot scroll terminal window when in vi

Tags: command-line, mouse, vi

With terminal settings

```
  Default/Layout/Screen Buffer Size/Height = 9999
  Properties/Layout/Screen Buffer Size/Height = 9999
```

I can scroll in the window using the mouse wheel.

Now I enter vi (a longer text than the window to show if scroll occurs inside vi).
Scrolling the terminal with the mouse wheel is not possible and the window scrollbar is greyed out. Scrolling inside vi does not happen either so the mouse is not directed to vi scrolling.

The odd thing is that the terminal setting is changed on entering vi:

```
  Properties/Layout/Screen Buffer Size/Height = 60
```

When exiting vi the Height returns to 9999.

How can I make the mouse wheel scroll the terminal windows? Ie. preventing vi from setting terminal Height temporarily?

NB: If anyone ask why I ask what I ask: my work habit is to scroll back in terminal history to copy things I paste into vi, so my question is for real use. My habit through 40 years of Unixing. It works in PuTTY ... but I want to stay with the default Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; you mention Ubuntu and terminal - but no clues as to if this is a text terminal (Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Core) or a GUI system (Ubuntu Desktop), nor if you're talking about `vi` or `vim` etc as no release details are provided.

Comment: Cannot reproduce that in a default Ubuntu 22.04 install with the default vi application.